# Checking values over a list of columns

Tags: r

I've a survey dataset where I need to check several question alternative answers (columns) in order to determine whether the respondent didn't answer the items. I can infer this by looking how many "No" the respondent has in a particular set of items. 
For instance, with the following example, I'd like check from column 2 to 6 whether: (1) a respondent has answered 'No' for all alternatives. If so, (2) the No's must become NAs in that range for each row.

```
mydat <- data.frame(ID=sample(n, n, FALSE),
Q01=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q02=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q03=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q04=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q05=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))), 
Q06=factor(sample(c('Yes', 'No', 'NA'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.5,.3,.2))),
Q07=factor(sample(c('Female', 'Male'), n, TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks only Q1-Q7 to see if the respondent answered No.  If all Q1-Q7 are No, then the NA's in that row are set to NA

```
set.seed(321)
n <- 20
mydat <- data.frame(ID=sample(n, n, FALSE),
Q01=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q02=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q03=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q04=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))),
Q05=factor(sample(c('No', 'Yes'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.6,.3))), 
Q06=factor(sample(c('Yes', 'No', 'NA'), n, TRUE, prob = c(.5,.3,.2))),
Q07=factor(sample(c('Female', 'Male'), n, TRUE)))
```

Check which are No

```
chk_answer <- rowSums(mydat[, 2:7] == "No") == 6
which(chk_answer)
[1] 10
```

And assign that row to NA

```
mydat[chk_answer, 2:7] <- NA
mydat
   ID  Q01  Q02  Q03  Q04  Q05  Q06    Q07
1  20   No  Yes   No   No   No   NA Female
2  18  Yes   No   No   No   No  Yes Female
3   5  Yes   No   No   No   No   No Female
4  19   No  Yes   No  Yes  Yes   No   Male
5   7   No  Yes  Yes   No   No   NA Female
6   6  Yes   No   No   No  Yes   No   Male
7  16  Yes   No  Yes   No   No  Yes   Male
8   4   No  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes   No Female
9  15   No   No   No  Yes   No   NA   Male
10  9 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> Female
11 14   No   No   No   No   No  Yes Female
12 13  Yes   No   No   No   No  Yes   Male
13 10  Yes   No   No   No   No  Yes   Male
14  1  Yes   No  Yes  Yes   No   No   Male
15 11   No   No  Yes  Yes   No  Yes   Male
16  2   No  Yes  Yes   No  Yes   NA Female
17  3  Yes   No   No  Yes  Yes   No   Male
18 17   No   No  Yes  Yes   No  Yes   Male
19  8  Yes   No   No   No   No  Yes   Male
```